Why I'm having issues to download image crate when compiling a rust app. No issue with others crates
When I try to compile any app that requires image crate (direct or indirect dependency) I'm receiving the follow message:
Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache
warning: spurious network error (3 tries remaining): [28] Timeout was reached (failed to download any data for `image v0.25.1` within 30s)
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [28] Timeout was reached (failed to download any data for `image v0.25.1` within 30s)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): [56] Failure when receiving data from the peer (Recv failure: Connection was reset)
error: failed to download from `https://static.crates.io/crates/image/0.25.1/download`

Cargo downloads some part of the crate but not all, it always stops when ~4,3Mb is still missing. All other dependencies are downloaded normally. I'm behind a corporate firewall, self signed certificates, and whatever other things big corps use today. I already tried with version 0.24.9 and 0.25.1, same result.
When I download the crate manually (https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/image/0.25.1/download) it works. But... what I need to do with the .crate file? I also was able to get the tarball (.xz), same, what to do with it?
I'm on windows 10.
I already, with no success:

cleaned my .cargo folder
completely remove rust and installed it again
tried to download the crate manually and add it to .cargo folder manually, copying it where the others crates are.
Retry next day, retry next week

I'm expecting to download and compile image crate using cargo automatically.

I had the same issue even with CARGO_HTTP_MULTIPLEXING=false and could not load dependency from local file after downloading it.
This worked for me :
Replace [dependency.image] by this line in [dependency]
image = { git = "https://github.com/image-rs/image", version = "0.25.1", optional = true, default-features = false, features = ["png"] }

when installing rav1e
